# Creating individual files from awk output

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to use a script to create several files inside a directory but am struggling with creating separate files for the output from awk.

the awk command is as follows:

```
$ awk '{ if ($3>=20 && $3<==30 && $5=="Sequenced") print $6 }' ./foo.txt
```

This produces an example output of:

```
cat 
dog
mouse
```

What I want to do is to create 3 files from this output that would be say cat.txt, dog.txt, mouse.txt inside a directory ./animals.  I would appreciate any help I can get with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ if ($3>=20 && $3<==30 && $5=="Sequenced") print $6".txt" }' ./foo.txt|xargs touch
```

using xargs you can transfer your output to argument list to another command, for example touch. It will creates empty files (or updated modification time if file exists)

Comment: Hi!  Thank you very much for your suggestion.  The command did work however I want to put it inside another directory.  Do you know how I can add that to this command?

Answer (score 1):

You have one extra `=` in `$3<==30`. Fixed below.

```
awk '$3>=20 && $3<=30 && $5=="Sequenced"{ #No need for if here
    file="./animals/"$6".txt"             #Build the file name
    printf "">file                        #Creates the empty file
    close(file)}' ./foo.txt               #Close the stream
```

One-liner:

```
awk '$3>=20&&$3<=30&&$5=="Sequenced"{f="./animals/"$6".txt";printf "">f;close(f)}' ./foo.txt
```